# android LocationRequest is private

Tags: java, android

I want to get driver current location in uber clone. When I write this code:

```
locationRequest=LocationRequest.create();
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
```

I get the error:

> Cannot resolve method 'create' in 'LocationRequest'

And when I write

```
mLocationRequest=new LocationRequest();
```

I get this error:

> 'LocationRequest()' has private access in 'android.location.LocationRequest'

[num 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdmAd.png)

[num 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCzB4.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LocationRequest.Builder(long intervalMillis)` instead `LocationRequest()`.

Answer (score 10):

`LocationRequest.Builder` works with 1 or 2 parameters.
This is the code that worked for me :

```java
 mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 1000)
                .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)
                .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(500)
                .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(1000)
                .build();
```

Comment: But only: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)

Comment: @guenter47: am I right that : In general, for all depredated methods we must add an `if (Build.VERSION ...` to that code? Or the new method will work on lower android versions?

Comment: Exactly so, if new methods are used in an older build, if(Build.Version ... ) should be used. If necessary with ... else if(Build.Version ... older) and if necessary ... else ... for the minSdkVersion

Answer (score 6):

in my case i was importing wrong file.

this is right file
"import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;"

Answer (score 0):

Number 0 is the right answer but that import

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;

is deprecated. I use that line and it solve the problems. But it need to be updated.

Comment: There is no answer "0". The "0" is the number of upvotes of this answer which might change.
You can leave a upvote yourself to indicate, that the answer worked for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error happened because of duplicate of LocationRequest imports unexpectedly as below. Having the first one removed fixed the error.

```
import android.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
```